# Move an ImageView in a circular path

Tags: java, android, floating-point, imageview, geometry

I need to move an ImageView in a circular path.

**The Specifications for the program:**

1) Each ImageView has a meteor class that contains the ImageView's

- Current coordinates
- Target coordinates
- and a few other various variables and functions

2) When the target coordinates are set the ImageView will move to them at the correct speed

3) The equation for the path of the circle I am using is k+sqrt(-h^2+2*h*x+r^2-x^2) (Top half), k-sqrt(-h^2+2*h*x+r^2-x^2) (bottom half)

below is the code I use the calculate the target coordinates of the top half of the circle.

```
              if(meteor.getXCoord() == meteor.getTargetCoordsX() && meteor.getXCoord() != meteor.getH() + meteor.getR()) {
                     if (meteor.getYCoord() == meteor.getTargetCoordsY()) {

                         /*
                             b+sqrt(-a^2+2*a*x+r^2-x^2), b-sqrt(-a^2+2*a*x+r^2-x^2)
                          */

                         meteor.setDeltaX(meteor.getSpeedX() + meteor.getXCoord());
                         meteor.setDeltaY(meteor.getSpeedY() + meteor.getYCoord());

                         meteor.setTargetCoordsX(meteor.getDeltaX());

                         //where target coordinate y is set *****
                         meteor.setTargetCoordY((meteor.getK() + (float) Math.sqrt(-1 * meteor.getH() * meteor.getH() + 2 * meteor.getH() * meteor.getDeltaX() + meteor.getR() * meteor.getR() - meteor.getDeltaX() * meteor.getDeltaX())));


                         //bottom half
                     }

               }
```

My problem is, the target coordinate y becomes NaN according to logcat after the first run through.
Also, according to Log.d every value used to set target coordinate y is set properly. 
Additional information:

- TargetCoord y & x are floats
- h, k, and r are floats
- delta x & y are floats
- current coordinates x & y are floats

Delta x & y are set above. The values used to set it are speed and current coordinates. speed is the number of pixels moved in 1 millisecond

Also, all meteor.methods have been tested, and work. I think the problem has to do with the calculation of target coordinate y.

Comment: Calculate argument value for `sqrt`and check whether it is non-negative before `sqrt` call

Comment: It is negative. Unfortunately, I can't understand why though.

Comment: possible reasons: 1) your logical mistake  2) very small negative value due to  floating calculation error

Comment: awesome, thank-you. I was just typing out the values logcat prints out, and I guess I miss read it delta x and y are zero which is probably the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It might be easier to use a little trigonometry: if you're rotating around (`x0`,`y0`) at constant speed, the coordinate updates can be written as

```
xn = x0 + (x-x0)*cos(u) + (y-y0)*sin(u)
yn = y0 - (x-x0)*sin(u) + (x-x0)*cos(u)
```

where `u` is the angular velocity. This avoids the need to take `sqrt`.

Comment: Awesome, thanks. I'll play with it, on the weekend. I actually was having a problem with getting a constant speed, as the x speed and y speed are different, because of varying screen sizes.

Comment: I looked over your method, and it seems good, but I'm going to keep my current method in-order to be consistent with the way I move for all my other patterns.